# Next/Previous jQuery control class jumps too many list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow

I have multiple content sliders on one page. Each slider's HTML is the entire HTML structure below. All it does is display the next/previous image in an unordered list. The number of sliders is dynamic. The code I have put together works fine for the first time I use a slider, but every other time the 'active' class jumps over other list items depending on how many different sliders I use. Do I need to reset something? I can't seem to find this specific problem anywhere.

The jQuery:

```
$('.portfolio-link').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().next().find('#slider li:first-child').addClass('active');
    $('.nav-container .next').click(function(){
        if (!$('#slider li.active').is(':last-child')){
            $('#slider li.active').next().addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
        };
    });
    $('.nav-container .prev').click(function(){
        if (!$('#slider li.active').is(':first-child')){
            $('#slider li.active').prev().addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
        };
    });
});
```

The relevant HTML structure:

```
<div class="portfolio-container">
    <div class="mask">
        <a class="portfolio-link">View more</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="portfolio-content">
    <div class="inner-portoflio-content">
        <div class="portfolio-slideshow">
            <div class="slider-container">
                <ul id="slider">
                    <li>Slide info</li>
                    <li>Slide info</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-container">
                <a class="next">Next</a>
                <a class="prev">Previous</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

every time your `.portfolio-link` is clicked you create a new event handler useless & messy + take advantage of `.on` to be free to add/remove element as you wish

```
$(document.body).on('click','.portfolio-link',function(){
   $(this).parent().parent().next().find('#slider li:first-child').addClass('active');
   })
.on ('click','.nav-container .next',function(){
    if (!$('#slider li.active').is(':last-child')){
        $('#slider li.active').next().addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
    }
})
.on('click','.nav-container .prev',function(){
    if (!$('#slider li.active').is(':first-child')){
        $('#slider li.active').prev().addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
    }
});
```